# C++ Container that can be Shared Across Process

Tags: c++, boost, data-structures, stl, containers

I am really curious to know whether there is any stl/boost/custom etc implementation of a container (map,vector, list etc) that can be used across multiple process.

Comment: Yes, see [**boost.interprocess**](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/interprocess/allocators_containers.html).

Comment: @juanchopanza Thank you very much. I shall have a try on it.

Comment: Do you mean inter-process or do you want to use it in an multi threaded environment?

Comment: @Klaus I meant inter process i.e. among multiple processes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, there is no STL, what was once the STL is now just the C++ standard library (actually there *is* still an STL but what most people mean when they say STL is the standard library).

And there is nothing in the standard library that gives you this cross-process capability.
That's not to say they won't work cross-process if you place them into, for example, shared memory, but that's not really built in to the collection.

And you could no doubt persist the data to disk but that's not really shared amongst processes in the sense you seem to mean.

Boost *does* give you the [interprocess](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/interprocess.html) stuff, which contains code for collections mirroring that found in C++, such as the vector, deque and list.

I have no doubt there *may* be some custom ones around somewhere but, at that level of interaction, most people would just opt for a database system, as it provides cross-process data quite easily, with all the useful stuff like race condition prevention, and so on.

Comment: Ehm, boost interprocess?

Comment: @juanchopanza: good point, I always thought that had just IPC in it, I guess I should have looked closer. I wasn't aware it shipped with a set of collection classes built specially for IPC use. Updated answer as per your comment, thanks.